# Dynamically made strings for id in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make id like this dynamically.

```html
<div id="track_1"></div>
<div id="track_2"></div>
```

So I gave the id like this from parent component.

```
export default function Components(props) {
  return (
      <AudioTrack trackNum="1"/>
      <AudioTrack trackNum="2"/>
  )
}
```

then in my AudioTrack Component I got the `trackNum` and want to use like this

```
const AudioTrack = (props) => {
  return(  
    <div id="track_{props.trackNum}" ></div>
  );
}
```

Howeber it doesn't work.

Is there any good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the div prop isn't a constant string, you need `{}` to indicate an expression, and then either use `+` to concatenate or a template literal with `${}`:

```
<div id={`track_${props.trackNum}`}></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I see I have used ` in javascript. That's I couldn't find out.